# Unreal engine UPROPERTY TsubclassOf not recognized

Tags: components, unreal-engine4

When I've created an ActorComponent c++ subclass with TSubclassOf UPROPERTY and set this class in blueprint I can't read read this property in c++ constructor.
In .h file I've got this:

```
protected:
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Setup")
        TSubclassOf<UBaseSkill> PrimarySkillClass;
```

And this in .cpp:

```
USkillSet::USkillSet()
{
if(PrimarySkillClass.Get())
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Creating skill"));
    }
    else
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("No skill class"));
    }
}
```

In BP I'm setting a class:
[BP screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9tFM.png)
so PrimarySkillClass.Get() should return true, but I'm getting "No skill class" in log. Why and how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor is the first method ever called on an object, it's to early on the life of the UObject. Properties, values from Blueprints and components are initialized afterwards.

So you have to access them later, either on [UObject::PostInitProperties()](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/UObject/PostInitProperties/index.html) or on BeginPlay() if it's not too late for your purpose.

Edit: interesting reading on [UObject Constructor, PostInitProperties and PostLoad](https://heapcleaner.wordpress.com/2016/06/11/uobject-constructor-postinitproperties-and-postload/)

Comment: Hm, this created new problem for me. Since I can't use CreateDefaultSubobject in constructor I need to use NewObject in begin play. This works, but the BeginPlay of created object isn't called. Is this a proper behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Never mind, turns out I've had to use RegisterComponent on created component.